# [Resloved]Font size won't grow big

Tags: php, html, css

I have been trying to make my fonts size bigger in my website. but trying all CSS,HTML and PHP does not work. I need it very big,i have tried the coding in other website but my website just won't work in my website,Am i doing something wrong or am i missing something?

Here is the code i am trying to add in

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
}

h1 {
    color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
   font-size: 2100;
  }
```

which works in other website but not in my.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Spelling Bee 2015</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>
<body>



<?php 
$userNames = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "words");

switch($userNames){
case '1':
echo "<p><center><fornt size='100'>Spell prophylactic</p></center></fornt>";
break;
case '2':
echo "<b><center><fornt size='100'>Spell irascible</b></center></fornt>";
}


?>

 </body>
```

The code above is where it will show up the words(which i want to make them big), which comes from a field set below.

```
        <center>
<div class="popupBoxContent">
<form method="get"
  action="data.php">
<fieldset>
<lable>
Enter Number:
</lable>

<input type = "text"
   name = "words"
     value = ""/>
<input type ="submit">
</input>
</fieldset>    
</div>
</center>
```

Please tell me if i am doing anything wrong,Thanks

Comment: Your title is very unclear, change it and make something related to your issue.

Comment: Your title is likely to not gain you attention. That type of title is clearly not accepted here. It is even stated in how to ask a question the right way. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, try posting your full html and css for us next time. But the issue you are having with font is a missing px or em at the end of 2100.

Comment: Is your path to the stylesheet correct? Why would you need a font of 2100px ? Have you tried using !important to see if it works? These are a few debugging questions that you should've asked yourself before posting a question here.

Comment: `echo "<p><center><fornt size='100'>SPELL FONT</p></center></fornt>";`.... and it doesn't have an `r` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First off**:

```
font-size: 2100;
```

needs a measurement, such as `em`, `%` or `px`, so change it to

```
font-size: 2100px;
```

which will certainly be a large font size!

---

**Next up**:

```
echo "<p><center><fornt size='100'>Spell prophylactic</p></center></fornt>";
```

You've spent `font` wrong (there's no `r`). Change it to:

```
echo "<p><center><font size='100'>Spell prophylactic</p></center></font>";
```

---

**Finally**:

It's also not advisable to use "font" - give your `p` element a class, and change the `CSS` of that class.

Add this to your `CSS` code:

```
p.custom {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

and change your `p` tag to:

```
echo "<p class='custom'>Spell prophylactic</p>";
```

Comment: @Ben Ohh!! the irony. *"You've spent font wrong"*, umm you have actually spelt the "spelt" wrong!!! :P

Answer (score 1):

Add a type of unit for example:

Change

```
font-size: 2100;
```

To,

```
font-size: 2100px;
```

**Reading Material**

[CSS Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: what it did after i put the 'px' it did not make it bigger , but in fact it make in lower at page, so i need to scroll all the way down.

Comment: Screenshot it please.

Answer (score 0):

Use em instead.

```
font-size: 2em;
font-size: 35em; /*or whatever*/
```

Also, your tags are messed up in your php. You put

```
<p><fornt> </p></fornt>
```

You need

```
<p><font> </font></p>
```

Close your inside tags before your outside tags.

Finally, if you are trying to change the size of the font inside a p element, don't set an inline style for font size also. The inline font size will overwriting your css rule. In fact, don't use a font tag at all. Use a class on your p element like was suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code.

Just add a unit to the font size

```
p {
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
   font-size: 2100;
  }
```

Make it:

```
p {
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
   font-size: 2100px;
  }
```

or use em if you consider responsiveness.
so it will be:
    p {
       font-family: "Times New Roman";
       font-size: 21em;
      }

Play around with the em values till you get desired result.

Comment: Yes,thanks for telling, but i had tried all those and it won't work